# Which 14.04 version should I install?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, ram, cpu

My specific question is that I have 3.9GB of ram, but I don't have an AMD processor. I have the Intel i5. Do I install i386, or the AMD x64 version of 14.04? Let me know if there are other specifics I should tell you guys.

Comment: The Intel Core i5 processor is a 64-bit architecture CPU. You should install Ubuntu 64-bit (amd64). There are several Ubuntu derivatives to choose from. Ubuntu is the most user-friendly derivative for a new Ubuntu user.

Comment: @karel I don't quite get why this wasn't posted as an answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the amd64-version, becuase your CPU (intel i5) is a 64-bit CPU.